# if $f$ homolorphic on $|z| \leq 2$ and $f'(0)=f(0)=0$ then $|f(z)| \leq M|z|^2$ for $|z| \leq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> if $f$ homolorphic on $|z| \leq 2$ and $f'(0)=f(0)=0$ then
>
> $$|f(z)| \leq M|z|^2$$ for $|z| \leq 2$.

I'm thinking $0=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0} = \frac{f(z)}{z}$ for $z \in D(0,2)\{0\}$ and $a_0=f(0)=0$ on $z_0=0$.

Then I guess Maximum Modulus Principle on $D(0,1)$ for $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ but no clue how to proceed.

Comment: Why do you have $0=(f(z)-f(0)/(z-0)$? Only the limit of the quantity as $z\to 0$ is $0$.

Comment: correct, I meant to expand to $z=0$ with the derivative.

Comment: Furthermore, holomorphicity is defined for domains (in particular, for open sets)? What do you mean by being holomorphic in a closed set?

Comment: I know it's for open discs but that's how the question was set.

Comment: @Gary it is generally meant that $f$ is defined and holomorphic on an open set $U$ containing the closed disk $|z| \le 2$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thank you. Yes, that is what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

For $|z|\le 2$, we can write $$f(z)=a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots$$hence for $z\ne 0$ $$|{f(z)\over z^2}|=|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_2z^{n-2}|$$Since $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_2z^{n-2}$ is also holomorphic over the compact disk $|z|\le 2$, it is continuous and bounded such that $$|{f(z)\over z^2}|=|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_2z^{n-2}|\le M$$hence the result.